# Speed up Numpy vector and C++/DLL single float function

Tags: python, numpy, dll

Q: Is there something like `numpy.(C/C++)vectorize` ?

Suppose I have a `numpy` vector and a C++ DLL (with C extern interface) containing a function accepting a float and returning a float (no array!). With `ctypes` I can wrap the DLL function and do `numpy.vectorize` on that, so I can write:

```
myfunc = numpy.vectorize(lambda x: ctypes_wrapped_DLL_fun(x))

x_vec = numpy.linspace(...) # a vector
print myfunc(x_vec)
```

Works like a charm. Of course this function call is slow, because it has to pass from the C-ish numpy context with every single value through python, through the DLL and back.

I have found a [mindboggling array of ways to interface C/C++ with numpy](https://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/interfacing_with_c/interfacing_with_c.html). Essentially only the chapter about Cython 2.8.5.2. "Numpy Support" gives an indication how to deal with vectors without going through the numpy/python/C interfaces all the time with every single element of the vector. The downside of this is that I would have to change the interface of the DLL from simple floats to arrays (and it liked to crash because I probably did things wrong).

[`numpy.ctypeslib`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html)also seems not to be what I need, because it also would require the DLL to have an array interface.

Any good examples for that (? I do not mind use Cython or another solution requiring a compiler. I would strongly prefer not to change the interface of the DLL.

Comment: You can create a whole new ufunc reusing the numpy machinery and your pointwise float-to-float function, see [this tutorial](https://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/advanced_numpy/#universal-functions) for a worked out example including Cython code.

Comment: I tried this (ufunc) also and failed miserably. I have to admit I am horrible at C/C++ and compilers. Did it work for you?